# roslaunch pr2_empty_world.launch not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am attempting to see the OMPL in action, so I was folling part 6 of the [MoveArmJointGoal tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm/Tutorials/MoveArmJointGoal).

When I attempt to `roslaunch pr2_empty_world.launch` gazebo briefly opens, then suddenly closes with some red text left in the console.

Here are the last few lines of the console output:

```
loading model xml from ros parameter
attempting to spawn robot in simulation
waiting for service spawn_urdf_model
directory [/tmp/gazebo-ollie-0] already exists (previous crash?)
the owner gazebo server (pid=30032) is not running.
deleting the old information of the directory [/tmp/gazebo-ollie-0]
Param [quickStep] is deprecated: [replace quickStep with stepType]
Param [quickStepIters] is deprecated: [replace quickStepIters with stepIters]
Param [quickStepW] is deprecated: [replace quickStepW with stepW]
Gazebo successfully initialized
[ INFO] [1299245159.191944453]: Starting to spin camera_synchronizer at 100.000000 Hz...
[ INFO] [1299245160.622058119, 0.001000000]: INFO: gazebo_ros_laser plugin artifically sets minimum intensity to 101.000000 due to cutoff in hokuyo filters.
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
spawning success None
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 30174, exit code -11].
log files: /home/ollie/.ros/log/ecba1f0e-4662-11e0-92e8-00e09122c142/gazebo-2*.log
[base_hokuyo_node-15] process has died [pid 30307, exit code -11].
log files: /home/ollie/.ros/log/ecba1f0e-4662-11e0-92e8-00e09122c142/base_hokuyo_node-15*.log
[tilt_hokuyo_node-16] process has died [pid 30309, exit code -11].
log files: /home/ollie/.ros/log/ecba1f0e-4662-11e0-92e8-00e09122c142/tilt_hokuyo_node-16*.log
[camera_synchronizer_node-17] process has died [pid 30311, exit code -11].
log files: /home/ollie/.ros/log/ecba1f0e-4662-11e0-92e8-00e09122c142/camera_synchronizer_node-17*.log
```

Is there anything else I need to do prior to launching?
Here are the logs mentioned above:

- [gazebo-2*.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/575474/)
- [base_hokuyo_node-15.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/575476/)
- [tilt_hokuyo_node-16.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/575478/)
- [camera_synchronizer_node-17.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/575479/)

Running c-turtle installed from the debian packages, ubuntu 10.10, 256MB 8600M, 2.4GHz Core2Duo, 3GB ram, etc.
Thanks in advance,

-Oliver

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9282/roslaunch-pr2_empty_world.launch-not-working/) by [omwdunkley](https://answers.ros.org/users/209/omwdunkley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [system requirements page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements) to see if your GPU/GPU driver is supported.

If your driver is not on the list, you can check to see if you have direct rendering capability for image sensor simulations and the gazebo gui:

```
$ glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions: ...
```

Without proper GPU support, you can try [running headless](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/RunningSimulatorHeadless).

If above doesn't apply, please also post a backtrace for further diagnostics.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omwdunkley](https://answers.ros.org/users/209/omwdunkley/) on 2011-03-05**:
Thanks for your reply hsu. Direct rendering is enabled, and I have had (a while back) some form of a PR2 simulation running in it before (cant remember which one). How exactly do I do this backtrace, and what exactly of? Thanks!